# Conflicts installing Python and R via Anaconda Navigator

Tags: r, python-3.x

I am attempting to create a new environment using Anaconda (Navigator) with Python 3.9.7 and R (pretty much any version, but the newer the better). No matter what version of R I attempt to install, Anaconda gives an error (example at the end of this post). I am having a hard time interpreting the error messages, other than the obvious implication that there are compatibility issues between Python and R. Is this specific to my system or do other people have the same issue? If the latter, is there a good place to see a compatibility matrix for various versions of Python and R?

---

**Example error produced when trying to install Python 3.9.7 and R 3.6.0**

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package r-base conflicts for:
r-essentials -> r-base[version='3.2.1.*|3.2.2.*|3.2.2|3.3.1.*|3.3.2.*|3.4.1.*|>=3.4.2|>=3.4.3,=3.5.0,=3.5.1,=3.6,=3.3.2|>=3.3.1']
r-essentials -> r-formatr[version='>=1.5'] -> r-base[version='3.1.3.*|3.2.0.*|>=3.4.2,r-base=3.6.0

Package python conflicts for:
r-essentials -> notebook[version='>=5.6.0'] -> python[version='>=2.7,=3.10,=3.8,=3.9,=3.7,=3.6,=3.5,python=3.9

Package tk conflicts for:
r-base=3.6.0 -> tk[version='>=8.6.8,r-essentials -> r-base[version='>=3.6, tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.7,=8.6.8,r-base=3.6.0 -> bwidget -> tk[version='>=8.6.7,python=3.9 -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,
Package openssl conflicts for:
python=3.9 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1h,=1.1.1i,=1.1.1j,=1.1.1k,=1.1.1l,r-base=3.6.0 -> curl -> openssl[version='1.0.*|>=1.0.2m,=1.1.1d,=1.1.1a,=1.0.2o,=1.1.1l,=1.1.1k,=1.1.1g,=1.1.1c,=1.1.1b,